# An inequality on sumsets.

Tags: combinatorics, sumset

Given two finite sets $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}$, can we assert the inequality $$|A+B|^2\ge |A+A|\cdot|B+B|?$$

I tried to construct an injective function from $(A+A)\times (B+B)$ to $(A+B)^2$ but failed to make the function injective.

It's a problem from my classmates, I'm not 100% sure if it's true.

Comment: Searching Math.SE for "sumset" revealed that this is false even for $B=-A$, see **[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914997/an-old-question-about-sumsets-and-difference-sets)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in zhoraster's comment this is false even for $B=-A,$ see "[An old question about sumsets and difference sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914997/an-old-question-about-sumsets-and-difference-sets)".